# Xcode 6.3.2, Not able to select Provision profile

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.3.2

I have install latest Xcode 6.3.2, and create new project.But, now I am not able to see dropdown into "Provisioning Profile".

Instead of showing drop down, it show me text area to type into it.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Check in the Accounts panel that you have one provision profile. If not, XCode will manage it for you

Comment: I have added profile manually. Before two minutes, it was showing me profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. There is one option into "Editor" menu named "Show value". 
I click on it and it is showing me dropdown into Profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode account preferences, accounts tab. Make sure you've added Apple ID to Xcode. If already yes, click View Details and then click refresh button to refresh all provisioning profiles.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I have remove all accounts from preferences & add new one. But still same issue :(